CSS not compressed using VITE and LARAVEL on HERIKU
I am using laravel 11 and vite to compress my css and js files.
In local environment, I am using npm run dev. And in my layout I have this directive :
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])

with that , each time I save something there are a compressed css file in public/build/asset.
When I deploy that in production, on heroku, I see the compression in the logs
    -----> Build
       Running build
       
       > build
       > vite build
       
       vite v5.2.11 building for production...
       transforming...
       ✓ 53 modules transformed.
       rendering chunks...
       computing gzip size...
       public/build/manifest.json             0.27 kB │ gzip:  0.15 kB
       public/build/assets/app-C4BDN1ig.css   0.56 kB │ gzip:  0.34 kB
       public/build/assets/app-C1-XIpUa.js   34.12 kB │ gzip: 13.62 kB
       ✓ built in 319ms
       
-----> Caching build
       - npm cache

Fine !
But when I get a page , I see that the compressed files are note used at all. It is the not compressed files which are used (of course I cleared the cache of my browser)
In my package.json file, I have these commands :
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
},

And in heroku I have these 2 packages installed

What can be my mistakes ?

I edited th question

What are your pages using then? Can you open the console browser and check for errors?

There are no errors in the console. The page is (for example) this one : https://doctodom-078a50a82259.herokuapp.com/the-author
